# Unravel - Coldwood Interactive

Tags: game-engine, development-environment

does somebody know what *Coldwood Interactive* used to develop Unravel,which game engine,programming languages or other tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The engine used is [PhyreEngine](http://develop.scee.net/research-technology/phyreengine/), a free to use engine made by **Sony**, which work with a lot of platforms and got some cool functionnalities apparently.

*Journey*, *Flower*, and some other really sweet games were developed using that engine :).

Comment: @GabrielRăducan My pleasure ! By the way, the Game Development community might be a better place for that kind of question (you can find it at the top left corner of StackOverflow), even tho this community might be a bit less reactive, the answer should be more specialized !